# Localizar restaurantes próximos cadastrados no banco de dados através do google maps

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

Estou precisando de uma ajuda. Eu possuo um sistema em PHP com um banco de dados mysql com varios restaurantes cadastrados, com campos como: id, nome, endereço, longitude e latitude e estou criando uma aplicação com o Ionic usando AngularJS.

Nessa aplicação eu precisava fazer com que o usuário ao colocar o endereço em que ele se encontra (através do google maps api), aparecesse os restaurantes cadastrados no banco de dados mais próximos do endereço do usuário, listados por proximidade.

Alguém sabe algum tutorial ou lógica de como posso fazer essa aplicação?

Por exemplo: é possível através da api do google maps fazer uma aplicação como essa: http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator/search/?

Comment: acho melhor você desenvolver com código nativo, java, xml, chave da API do google maps e etc.

Comment: Uma dica, pode usar a linguagem e estrutura que quiser! Para pesquisar, envie a localização atual pro servidor php, nele faça o cálculo de `havesine` (Pesquise aqui no stackoverflow mesmo, tem respostas ótimas!) Depois de um `die(json_encode($variavel))`

Comment: Todas linguagens de frotend, mobile ou não, trabalham muito bem com json para renderizar conteúdos

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que usar o Cordova para pegar a longitude e a latitude do celular , via GPS, se ele for digitar ai fica mais fácil , com este dados você aumenta quantos kms você quer, ampliando a longitude e a latitude, fazendo um raio de quantos kms precisa. Para calcular tem este aqui https://gist.github.com/rafaellyra/5180762